# What happens if I reference a package but don't use/require it?

Tags: perl

As much as I can (mostly for clarity/documentation), I've been trying to say

```
use Some::Module;
use Another::Module qw( some namespaces );
```

in my Perl modules that use other modules.

I've been cleaning up some old code and see some places where I reference modules in my code without ever having `use`d them:

```
my $example = Yet::Another::Module->AFunction($data); # EXAMPLE 1
my $demo = Whats::The::Difference::Here($data);       # EXAMPLE 2
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a performance impact (I'm thinking compile time) by not stating `use x` and simply referencing it in the code?
2. I assume that I shouldn't `use` modules that aren't utilized in the code - I'm telling the compiler to compile code that is unnecessary.
3. What's the difference between calling functions in example 1's style versus example 2's style?

Comment: You might want to ask one question per question in the future. ;)

Comment: Note that, in `use Another::Module qw( some namespaces )`, the *namespace* is `Another::Module` whereas `some namespaces` is two identifiers that you want to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that this falls firmly into the category of *preemptive optimisation* and *if you're not sure, then leave it in*. You would have to be including some vast unused libraries if removing them helped at all

It is typical of Perl to hide a complex issue behind a simple mechanism that will generally *do what you mean* without too much thought

The simple mechanisms are these

- `use My::Module 'function'` is the same as writing

  ```
  BEGIN {
      require My::Module;
      My::Module->import( 'function' );
  }
  ```
- The first time perl successfully executes a `require` statement, it adds an element to the global `%INC` hash which has the "pathified" module name (in this case, `My/Module.pm`) for a key and the *absolute location* where it found the source as a value
- If another `require` for the same module is encountered (that is, it already exists in the `%INC` hash) then `require` does nothing

So your question

#### What happens if I reference a package but don't `use`/`require` it?

We're going to have a problem with *use*, *utilise*, *include* and *reference* here, so I'm code-quoting only `use` and `require` when I mean the Perl language words.

Keeping things simple, these are the three possibilities

- As above, if `require` is seen more than once for the same module source, then it is ignored after the first time. The only overhead is checking to see whether there is a corresponding element in `%INC`
- Clearly, if you `use` source files that aren't needed then you are doing unnecessary compilation. But Perl is damn fast, and you will be able to shave only fractions of a second from the build time unless you have a program that uses enormous libraries and looks like `use Catalyst; print "Hello, world!\n";`
- We know what happens if you make method calls to a class library that has never been compiled. We get

  ```
  Can't locate object method "new" via package "My::Class" (perhaps you forgot to load "My::Class"?)
  ```
- If you're using a *function* library, then what matters is the part of `use` that says

  ```
  My::Module->import( 'function' );
  ```

  because the first part is `require` and we already know that `require` never does anything twice. Calling `import` is usually a simple function call, and you would be saving nothing significant by avoiding it
- What is perhaps less obvious is that big modules that include multiple subsidiaries. For instance, if I write just

  ```
  use LWP::UserAgent;
  ```

  then it knows what it is likely to need, and these modules will also be compiled

  ```
  Carp
  Config
  Exporter
  Exporter::Heavy
  Fcntl
  HTTP::Date
  HTTP::Headers
  HTTP::Message
  HTTP::Request
  HTTP::Response
  HTTP::Status
  LWP
  LWP::MemberMixin
  LWP::Protocol
  LWP::UserAgent
  Storable
  Time::Local
  URI
  URI::Escape
  ```

and that's ignoring the pragmas!

Did you ever feel like you were kicking your heels, waiting for an `LWP` program to compile?

I would say that, in the interests of keeping your Perl code clear and tidy, it may be an idea to remove unnecessary modules from the compilation phase. But don't agonise over it, and *benchmark your build times* before doing any pre-handover tidy. No one will thank you for reducing the build time by 20ms and then causing them hours of work because you removed a non-obvious requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have a bunch of questions.

> 1. Is there a performance impact (thinking compile time) by not stating use x and simply referencing it in the code?

No, there is no performance impact, because you can't do that. Every namespace you are using in a working program gets defined somewhere. Either you `use`d or `require`d it earlier to where it's called, or one of your dependencies did, or another way<sup>1</sup> was used to make Perl aware of it

Perl keeps track of those things in symbol tables. They hold all the knowledge about namespaces and variable names. So if your `Some::Module` is not in the referenced symbol table, Perl will complain.

> 2. I assume that I shouldn't use modules that aren't utilized in the code - I'm telling the compiler to compile code that is unnecessary.

There is no question here. But yes, you should not do that.

It's hard to say if this is a performance impact. If you have a large Catalyst application that just runs and runs for months it doesn't really matter. Startup cost is usually not relevant in that case. But if this is a cronjob that runs every minute and processes a huge pile of data, then an additional module might well be a performance impact.

That's actually also a reason why all `use` and `require` statements should be at the top. So it's easy to find them if you need to add or remove some.

> 3. What's the difference between calling functions in example 1's style versus example 2's style?

Those are for different purposes mostly.

> ```
> my $example = Yet::Another::Module->AFunction($data); # EXAMPLE 1
> ```

This syntax is very similar to the following:

```
my $e = Yet::Another::Module::AFunction('Yet::Another::Module', $data)
```

It's used for class methods in OOP. The most well-known one would be `new`, as in `Foo->new`. It passes the thing in front of the `->` to the function named `AFunction` in the package of the thing on the left (either if it's `bless`ed, or if it's an identifier) as the first argument. But it does more. Because it's a *method call*, it also takes inheritance into account.

```
package Yet::Another::Module;
use parent 'A::First::Module';

1;

package A::First::Module;

sub AFunction { ... }
```

In this case, your example would also call `AFunction` because it's inherited from A::First::Module. In addition to the symbol table referenced above, it uses `@ISA` to keep track of who inherits from whom. See [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) for more details.

> ```
> my $demo = Whats::The:Difference::Here($data);        # EXAMPLE 2
> ```

This has a syntax error. There is a `:` missing after `The`.

> ```
> my $demo = Whats::The::Difference::Here($data);        # EXAMPLE 2
> ```

This is a function call. It calls the function `Here` in the package `Whats::The::Difference` and passes `$data` and nothing else.

Note that as [Borodin points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981526/what-happens-if-i-reference-a-package-but-dont-use-require-it/39981778#comment67242736_39981526), your function names are very atypical and confusing. Usually functions in Perl are written with all lowercase and with underscores `_` instead of camel case. So `AFunction` should be `a_function`, and `Here` should be `here`.

---

1) for example, you can have multiple `package` definitions in one file, which you should not normally do, or you could assign stuff into a namespace directly with syntax like `*Some::Namespace::frobnicate = sub {...}`. There are other ways, but that's a bit out of scope for this answer.

Comment: Doh, I implicitly knew the answer to #3, but I guess didn't think abot it hard enough when typing this up. Thanks for being to thorough and thoughtful!

Comment: Re #3, The difference is that `->` is a method call, so it uses inheritance and passes the invocant, whereas not using `->` is a sub call, which doesn't use inheritance and has no invocant. Could you mention inheritance please?

Comment: @DavidCrane: This is one reason why it's a bad idea to use capitals for function names.  The `Here` in `Whats::The::Difference::Here` is a function name while the rest of the identifier is a namespace, and it would be much clearer what was going on if you had written `Whats::The::Difference::here($data)`. The same applies to `Yet::Another::Module::AFunction`, which is much better as `Yet::Another::Module::a_function`.

Comment: @simbabque: Your answer to 3. needs reworking. *"This syntax is actually the same as this"* is just wrong, that's why one of them is called the *method call* syntax and the other one isn't. You're referring to the *semantic* difference, and if `Yet::Another::Module` is a subclass of, say `Super::Class`, then `Yet::Another::Module->class_method($data)` could easily be the same as `Super::Class::class_method('Yet::Another::Module', $data)`, so the semantics aren't the same either.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot about that part. But I can't edit now, I'm on my mobile. Will edit later.

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy atm

Comment: After the first sentence, #1 also needs reworking. There are many ways to define a namespace that doesn't get added to `%INC`, or to make an entry in `%INC` that does not create a corresponding namespace.

Comment: @mob I read that part as that the `use` and `require` ones go into `%INC`. But of course there are other ways to get Perl to know about namespaces.

Comment: Close enough :)

Comment: @simbabque: `%INC` is only about *compiled source files*. It is the symbol tables themselves that decide whether perl knows about `Any::Other:function()`, and those tables in combination with the `@ISA` arrays to decide whether it knows about `Any::Other->function()`.

Comment: @Borodin am I saying anything to the contrary? I don't have that information, but I'm not contradicting it either I believe. Let me work that in.

Comment: @Borodin this is turning into a rather complicated affair. I wonder if the OP comes back here to read it at all

Comment: @simbabque: The original question was already over-complicated, and I voted to close it as being *too broad*. It can be okay to write generalisations, but going into too much detail and getting it wrong is misleading. You still have *"So if your `Some::Module` is not in the referenced symbol table, Perl will complain"*, which is confusing because `Some::Module` ***is*** a package/symbol table. Yes, strictly speaking every symbol table is a member of itself, but is that what you meant? I think you should have steered clearly away from that!